# Classic ASP Paypal IPN Refund

Tags: asp-classic, paypal-ipn

Trying to troubleshoot some legacy Classic ASP Paypal IPN code. The legacy code works perfectly for Selling products. However, processing a REFUND from the Paypal account seems to be causing some issue for Paypal IPN. The IPN listener receives the Refund IPN message and processes the business logic correctly, marking the transaction Refunded. But, Paypal still marks the transaction IPN History as "Retrying" for some reason. Below is the sample code from GitHub that was used to create the IPN listener we're troubleshooting.

Does the post back to Paypal need to be different for Selling vs Refunding?

Any help is greatly appreciated. Cheers

```
<%@LANGUAGE="VBScript"%>
<%
Dim Item_name, Item_number, Payment_status, Payment_amount
Dim Txn_id, Receiver_email, Payer_email
Dim objHttp, str
' read post from PayPal system and add 'cmd'
str = Request.Form & "&cmd=_notify-validate"
' post back to PayPal system to validate
set objHttp = Server.CreateObject("Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP")
' set objHttp = Server.CreateObject("Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP.4.0")
' set objHttp = Server.CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
objHttp.open "POST", "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr", false
objHttp.setRequestHeader "Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
objHttp.Send str
' assign posted variables to local variables
Item_name = Request.Form("item_name")
Item_number = Request.Form("item_number")
Payment_status = Request.Form("payment_status")
Payment_amount = Request.Form("mc_gross")
Payment_currency = Request.Form("mc_currency")
Txn_id = Request.Form("txn_id")
Receiver_email = Request.Form("receiver_email")
Payer_email = Request.Form("payer_email")
' Check notification validation
if (objHttp.status <> 200 ) then
' HTTP error handling
elseif (objHttp.responseText = "VERIFIED") then
' check that Payment_status=Completed and other variables
Execute business process code, mark transaction Completed or Refunded from payment_status works successfully
elseif (objHttp.responseText = "INVALID") then
' log for manual investigation
else
' error
end if
set objHttp = nothing%>
```

Answer (score 0):

The postback to PayPal does not influence whether an IPN is marked as successfully received. The postback step is for your own verification that the IPN is from PayPal.

For an IPN to be successfully received, the HTTP response status must be 200 OK.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response and clarification. My server side is working correctly. It's Paypal recognizing my server has received the Refunded message that I'm having issue with. In the IPN History, the refund message is always shown as "Retrying". Enough of those errors and the IPN automatically shuts off. Selling IPN messages are marked as Sent in the IPN History. Should Refund messages be marked Sent as well?

Comment: For an IPN to be successfully received, the HTTP response status must be 200 OK.

Comment: Are you saying I need to make str equal "OK" in my HTTP POST for Refunds? Not the same as str for selling with the whole message with notify-validate appended to it? I really appreciate your help, I'm just not understanding what needs to change in my IPN listener code.

Comment: No, HTTP status 200 when the IPN is received. This has nothing to do with posting for validation.

Comment: Thank you for your continued help. I believe the HTTP status from Paypal is 200 OK as you suggest because my business code is executed properly. The IF conditions in the script say if it's not 200 report and error. If it is 200 execute business logic, which is what is happening. I just want to know why and how to fix Paypal knowing the message was accepted and marking the IPN message finalized instead of "Retrying" in the IPN history list.

Comment: Return an HTTP 200 status.

Comment: I noticed the Refund transactions in IPN History have and HTTP 500 error code. While the Selling transactions have a HTTP 200, as you suggested. I don't understand the difference because Selling and Refund execute the exact same query successfully. The update query is simply change the Payment Status equal to Payment_Status sent in IPN message. Sorry to continue on this topic, but I'm not having any success. Can you share an example of how to "Return an HTTP 200" status? Is it located after the query executes?

Comment: If something in your script errors, that will usually result in a 500 Internal Server Error. But the exact reason why you're returning 500 instead of 200 is something  you'll need to debug and research.